# oci_execute not working (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

Tags: php

I try to execute the Oracle Procedure, but it's become slow and timeout.
And the issues happen when I try to use "OCI_B_CLOB".

Here the code snippet:

```
$accountNumber = '676836484';

$sql = "CALL xapp.pkg_payway_utl_v4.get_acc_info(:in_acc, :io_data, :io_status, :io_error)";

$io_data = null;
$status = null;
$error = null;

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

$myLOB = oci_new_descriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':in_acc', $accountNumber);

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':io_data', $myLOB, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":io_status", $status, 200, SQLT_CHR);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":io_error", $error, 200, SQLT_CHR);

oci_execute($stid);
$clob = $myLOB->load();
$myLOB->free();
closeOracleCon($conn);

var_dump($clob);
exit;
```

Here's the response on the web browser:

[image]

Please help...

Comment: https://www.php.net/oci_new_descriptor ` type

    Valid values for type are: OCI_DTYPE_FILE, OCI_DTYPE_LOB and OCI_DTYPE_ROWID.
`

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with OCL. It uses an "OCI" API.